# Evaluating this line integral

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following line integral

$\int 2x+y \,dx +xy\,dy$ from $(-1,2)$ to $(2,5)$ where $y=x^2 +1$
When I integrated it w.r.t $x$ I found the integral

$$\int  2x^4 +3x^2 +2x+1 \, dx=\frac{141}{5}$$
from $x=-1$ to $x=2$

But when I tried it w.r.t $y$ I got a confusion with evaluating the limits of $y$ since $y=x^2 +1 $ then $x=\sqrt{y-1}$  where $y$ belongs to $[1,5]$
and $x=-\sqrt{y-1}$ where $y$ belongs to $[1,2]$

Comment: Could you please look at your formatting? It is not clear what is your integrand. Some parenthesis might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your evaluation
$$\int_C (2x+y)dx +xydy=\int_{x=-1}^2 ((2x+x^2+1) +x(x^2+1)(2x))dx=\frac{141}{5}$$
is correct. Using $y$ as a parameter is more difficult, but you should obtain the same result.
\begin{align*}
\int_C (2x+y)dx +xydy&=\int_{y=2}^1 ((2f(y)+y)f'(y) +f(y)y)dy
+\int_{y=1}^5 ((2g(y)+y)g'(y) +g(y)y)dy\\
&=\int_{y=2}^1 \left(1-\frac{y}{2\sqrt{y-1}} -y\sqrt{y-1}\right)dy\\
&\qquad+\int_{y=1}^5 \left(1+\frac{y}{2\sqrt{y-1}} +y\sqrt{y-1}\right)dy
\end{align*}
where $f(y)=-\sqrt{y-1}$ and $g(y)=\sqrt{y-1}$.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you i tried it and i got the same result also i found out my mistake was the changing of the orintation gives the limts of the first integral from 1 to 2 instead of 2 to 1

Comment: @HussienMohamed Are you sure that my answer was useful ?

Comment: Yes i checked it

Comment: But the integrand is the same in the two parts of the integral like the first one

Comment: @HussienMohamed Corrected. However they are not the same.

Comment: I did not ckeck it

Answer (score 0):

Use the parametrization $(t,t^2+1)$ and so,

\begin{align*} \int_{\mathcal{C}} 2x + ydx+ xy dy &= \int_{t=-1}^{t=2} 2t+ (t^2+1) + t(t^2+1)(2t) \ dt \\ \\ & = \int_{1}^2 2t^4+3t^2+2t+1  \ dt \end{align*}

and just finish from here. I don't know if you meant $2x+ydx$ or $(2x+y)dx$. I assumed the former, so if the latter, just make the appropriate change. In any case, I hope this helps.